# Restore incomplete iCloud backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

One month ago i lost my iPhone 5. Got a new one, 6S, and i'm trying to recover my old media. According to iCloud, there is a 1.5 GB Incomplete backup from the phone which is now gone. Is there anything I can do to salvage any of the data from this Incomplete 1.5 GB backup?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iCloud backups should be stored in:
`/Users/[user name]/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup`

You can use a backup extraction tool like [this one](http://download.cnet.com/iPhone-Backup-Extractor/3000-18553_4-75373326.html) (note that the free version is limited) to see what you can get from the backup, then transfer it to your phone via iTunes.

Comment: I wonder if this solution / suggestion is still valid. According to my iPhone settings, I have an existing iCloud backup of my iPhone (iOS 16.6.1) but there are no files under the above mentioned backup directory on my Mac (macOS 13.5.2) which is signed in with the same Apple ID as  my iPhone.