# iCloud - Recovering Data from Incomplete Backup (iOS 11)

Tags: ios, icloud, backup

I got a new iPhone and gave my old phone during the trade in, but I was unable to backup my old one completely. [A similar question has been asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229868/restore-incomplete-icloud-backup) which doesn't apply in my case, as I don't have the backup file on my computer.

My iCloud account shows 3.3 GB of backup, but not way to access it.

Under my iPhone's Settings app → iCloud → Manage Storage → Backups, I am able to see Last Backup → Incomplete and only *Delete Backup* as the option with no way to recover.

What existing data tools are there to recover the data? Does iCloud allow downloading the backup file directly?

I have both Windows and Mac computers so I can try to restore from either Operating System.

Comment: Can you follow the directions for Mac/PC [here](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204215#findiCloud)? (If you're using Windows you need [iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204283), a free program provided by Apple.) You may be able to get the backup file to your local computer that way. BTW it would also be very helpful to know if you are on macOS or Windows; please edit the question to say which.

Comment: @ThatsJustCheesy It seems those directions are just for "listing" the backups for not a way to download them to the Computer. (I don't even know if it automatically tries to sync to a local file directory)

Comment: I'm sorry that I may be of limited help, as I don't use iCloud backups. If you can't download the one labeled "incomplete" using the typical Apple methods, the only other option I've found is to see if iPhone Backup Extractor can do it (see https://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/guides/recover-icloud-data/). It costs money, though, so that's up to you. If someone else has a better solution then that would be great, which is why I won't post this as an answer. (If you do go this route, though, please do answer this question and say how it went!)

Comment: @ThatsJustCheesy Thank you. The problem is that `iPhoneBackupExtractor` only works if you have a backup. They don't deal with Incomplete backups.